# Android app force closes on a real device but works on emulator

Tags: android

My app has an action bar tabs with 3 fragments (1-list fragment with the list of running processes, 2-battery and memory info, 3-just some text). It works fine, with no errors on the emulator, but on a real device it starts ok, I go through the tabs several times and then it unexpectedly force closes. My phone isn't seen among the adb devices, so I don't know if there are any errors in the logcat. What could be the problem?

Comment: Android has a "protecting system" that tries to force close an app that its UI (main thread) doesn't response for 5 seconds. Depend on the calculations and processes you are doing in your app and the processing power you have (Which changes on the emulator and on a real device) your app UI thread might be "busy" for 5 seconds, causing android to try closing it.

Comment: Thx, and what could be the solution in such a situation?

Comment: If you do a lot of calculations in your app, causing the UI to stuck, you might consider using a new thread for those calculations, or even easier (In my opinion...), using `AsyncTask<T, T, T>` which explained [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 0):

First, enable debugging on your phone.  This is found on Settings.

There are several things that can crash the app on the device:

for example: Screen orientation;  on the emulator, your screen never rotates, but on a device the screen can be rotated unintentionally.  If the app is a prototype, several things can go wrong on rotation.

You should start by enabling debugging so you can pin-point the problem

Comment: I tried enabling debugging but still the phone isn't seen, and as for screen orientation , I didn't move the phone at all so I don't think it's the reason

Comment: What Operating System are you using for development ?